# what is the best way to install python 3.10.10 (which is the current version of 3.10) on a 22.04 machine where the systems python version is 3.10.6

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python3

I have done the following on a clean install of a 22.04 machine:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3.10 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

as one can see it's happy with the system version which is 3.10.6

without installing anaconda (which installs a BUNCH of stuff I don't need on the server)... what are my options so that I can detach people from the system version, which is not up to date?  I thought the point of adding deadsnakes was in part a way to resolve this, and/or installing prior versions.

also, I wanted to understand what is the recommended way of setting up the machine so that people using the machine are not using the system python and using a slightly different version of python. (eg: subversion differences like stated above)

to be clear I do not want to change the systems version of python.  I only want to change what the users... um... use. ;-)

I would like to use 3.10.10 for the bug fixes, I am assuming that 3.10.6 is the last security patch. I should also note that for an 18.04 machine we were ending up with 3.10.10 when we had it apt upgrade.

thus, 18.04 machines that are going through the do-release-upgrade to 22.04 end up with the following state:

```
python3
Python 3.10.10 (main, Feb  8 2023, 14:49:42) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

thus the clean install 22.04 machines are behind any of the 18.04's upgraded to 22.04.

one other item of note is 3.10.7, 3.10.8, and 3.10.9 are security patches... so I am wondering why the system patch is not at least at 3.10.9. see the python release notes for further details.

Comment: Please explain *why* you want 3.10.10 - the Python 3.10 version of Ubuntu is properly patched with security updates, so is there any reason why, except *"you would like the latest"*?

Comment: I added rational as to why, and noting that I do not want to change the system python.  also see comments about upgraded 18.04 machines.

Answer (score 4):

The deadsnakes ppa does *not* contain 3.10 for Jammy (22.04). So it's working as designed, telling you that there's no 3.10 other than the one you have installed. There *is* 3.11 and 3.12 for Jammy. But I certainly wouldn't replace the *system* python with those.

You may want to consider using virtualenv's to isolate your work for different python versions.

[image]

Comment: Another way to do it is with containers. With LXD you could spin up a container, and put a bespoke python version in it, and share the credentials for the container with your user. Each user could potentially have their own isolated container.

Comment: And yet another way to do this is to install the python version you want in userspace (after installing all the build dependencies from the repositories) with `pyenv` and then just create a venv around the userspace python you want to use.  If you don't want to use the PPA that is.